# unique index allowing for null values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have Message.rb that has column A, B, and C.

I added a unique index to Message like so:

```
add_index :messages, [:a, :b, :c], unique: true, name: 'mm_uniqueness'
```

however, I would like column A to be able to have a value of null without triggering the uniqueness restraint.

So:

```
original a=1, b=2, c=3
second   a=1, b=2, c=3 (not unique)

original a=null, b=2, c=3
second   a=null, b=2, c=3 (unique)
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create partial index:

```
add_index :messages, [:a, :b, :c], unique: true, name: 'mm_uniqueness', where: 'a != null'
```

Comment: turns out you don't even need it. by default, NULL is not counted towards the unique constraint.

Comment: In any case, 'a != null' always calculates to be NULL, since all SQL expressions involving NULL are NULL. A more correct (albeit as pointed out by @MatthewBerman unnecessary) would be to use `where: 'a IS NOT NULL'`